# PHP preg_match "AND" operator

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I use the "OR" operator "|" to match one of the words of the $name variable:

```
$name = "one five six two";
if (preg_match('/(one|two)/i', $name)) {return true;}
```

What operator should I use with [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to have an "AND" condition if those words are inside of $name?

For example,

```
if (preg_match('/(two "AND" five)/i', $name)) {return true;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still want to use regex, you'll need positive lookaheads:

```
if (preg_match('/^(?=.*one)(?=.*two)/i', $name)) {return true;}
```

It's not recommended for simple stuff (kind of overkill), and it gets messy with more complex stuff...

Comment: Can I use single preg_match function to check like: [anything beging]two[anything middle]five[anything end] ?

Comment: @KenTang Isn't that a single `preg_match`? Also, it looks for `one` and `two` anywhere in `$name`.

Comment: Does complex single function (?=.*one)(?=.*two) can uses more CPU resources and calculation time compare to double preg_match use?

Comment: @KenTang If `$name` is very long, yes. Otherwise, the difference shouldn't be too noticeable.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, helped a lot. Kudos to you mate.

Comment: @patrick: The question was somewhat ambiguous, but for the way he interpreted it, Jerry's answer is correct.  (For the other interpretation, you should have removed *both* lookaheads: `'/one.*two/i'`.)

Comment: @Alan, it could have done with removing both indeed, this didn't need positive lookahead at all. It definitely didn't need two though. And for an example on how to do a positive lookahead (something followed by something else) the two lookaheads were just confusing, so I removed one to make the example more clear.

Comment: @patrick:  Jerry, along with all the other responders, interpreted the question as how to match two particular words *in any order*.  That requires two lookaheads.  So you weren't simplifying the answer, you were changing it.

Comment: Here is some php stuff to complete the answer maybe it could be useful : preg_match('/^(?=.*'.implode(")(?=.*", $keyWords).')/i',  $libelle);

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to separate the two conditions and use `&&` as follows:

```
if(preg_match('/(two)/i', $name) && preg_match('/(five)/i', $name)) {
    return true;
}
```

Learn more [here](https://www.php.net/language.operators.logical).

Comment: Can I use single preg_match function to check like: [anything]two[anything]five[anything] ?

Answer (score 1):

You might just do this without resorting to regular expressions:

```
if (strpos($name, 'one') !== false && strpos($name, 'two') !== false) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Perhaps explain the equal `false` parts in your answer? (The documentation says *"Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function."*) - not the negation, but why it can't just be `strpos($name, 'one')` without `!== false`. (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or other meta talk - the answer should appear as if it was written today)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( preg_match('/two/i', $name) && preg_match('/five/i', $name) ) {return true;}
```

Comment: Can I use single preg_match function to check like: [anything]two[anything]five[anything] ?

Comment: Yes. Regular expressions can seem daunting at first, but if you spend a little time learning the basics it will pay off a lot in the long run. To answer the question in your comment: `preg_match('/.*two.*five.*/i', $name)` or if you want to match the entire string `$name` with this pattern then `preg_match('/^.*two.*five.*$/i', $name)`

Comment: The last comment seems to contradict [Jerry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222574/php-preg-match-and-operator/22223019#22223019).

Answer (score -2):

Don't use `preg_match` if you only match one word. A regular expression uses more computer resources compared to `strpos`.

Do not use `preg_match()` if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use `strpos()` or `strstr()` instead as they will be faster (from *php.net*).

```
if (str_pos($name, 'two') !== false
    && str_pos($name, 'five') !== false) {

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't the one to downvote, but matching one word with regexp can be VERY useful. Your example matches too when $name='fleetwood' for instance... regexp( '/\btwo\b/i', $name ) would not. Adding spaces to your $name and then doing a search would miss 'one, two, three', 'cause there is an `'` attached to the two. Again, the regexp would be the best solution in this case... "matching one word" is NOT the same as "one string is contained in another"